# Allow facebook login from iframed webpage

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

**setup**
 - domain A = http://www.domainA.com
 - domain B = http://www.domainB.com

On domainA I have a html page with this content

`...

< iframe src="http://www.domainB.com/fblogin.php" >< br >

...`

**fblogin.php** takes care of logging people in to facebook. Standalone that page works fine. In the iframe it does not.

**on facebook in my app settings** I obviously have to enter the Site URL to where Facebook will 'redirect' after people have authorized the app. I can do only 1 thing: enter my iframeing html page there ... but then, (expected) Facebook passes the necessary login parameters (state , etc) to that page , and not to the fblogin.php page that needs it to log in.
Would love to have some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back here to *lightly* answer my own question.
In the end I opted to use the Javascript SDK to log in (through a popup) / following the example on FB dev (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).
 Had no issues whatsoever after I made that choice.
As an extra measure to overcome the IE8 issue I was having, I ended up putting the following line in the header of my index.php to overcome a possible Privacy Issue in IE8 causing for problems. (you can see that by the little "eye" icon in the bottom toolbar when IE8 thinks something is not 'right' with the content of an iframe.

`header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');`

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow for a standard iFrame call - iFrames must fully redirect, otherwise Facebook simply won't authorize them. Redirect to the login URL using `target=top` , and this should allow users to authorize themselves/log in.

Comment: Thanx for the comment altho I'm not following the entire process you propose.
The biggest issue , I think is the fact that my return url (the one that I have to enter in my FB app settings) HAS to be the Iframing page for the user to be thrown back to the right 'landing page' ... but that Iframing page cannot do anything with the data it got back from FB as that's the job of the IFRAMED page. I'm sorry : my brain is fried at this stage. Thanks for the help.